# HTML to PDF without headless Chrome

Tags: node.js, html-to-pdf

I'm trying to find a solution to generate PDFs from HTML but everything I find used headless Chrome.

Does anyone know about a solution that doesn't involve using a headless Chrome instance?

Thanks!

Comment: The challenge here is that you need something that can render full-blown HTML to PDF.  That's a lot more than just parsing and understanding the HTML.  Unless it's a fairly expensive commercial product, it's likely going to have to be based on some open source HTML renderer (like Chromium).

Comment: It makes sense. I didn't have much hope because I didn't find anything. But I thought it was worth asking in case there was something I hadn't hear about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/), which despite its name produces PDF from HTML.
As a bonus it supports Paged Media CSS standards that no browser wants to support (as of today).

I have no relation to Prince, just have used it in the past.

Comment: Thanks! It is not a node package, right? but well, if it can be used from the terminal it may be useful too.

Comment: @JVLobo No it's a .exe.
I should have pointed out that it's a commercial product (if that makes any difference for you) and they have one license for personal, interactive usage; and one license for automated server generation of pdfs.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just wanted to find something for a small personal project so I think PrinceXML is out of my budget sadly :(